# Electronically Signing Emails From Built-in Workflows

Tags: workflow, email, configuration

Is there any way to electronically sign an email that originates from one of the built in SharePoint workflows? We have an internal policy that restricts users from following links in emails that are not signed by a trusted source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, definitely not. You will have to build a custom workflow with a custom E-Mail activity.

Comment: That was what I thought. Thank you for the confirmation.